# Плагин Slick. Высота блока

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

Внутри каждого блока **slick-slider__i** есть изображение. Каждое больше следующего, но не смотря на то, что у блоков стоит **height: 100%**, они не растягиваються относительно высоты родителя.

[image: Img]

Как сделать высоту блока 100%?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slickOpts = {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rows: 0,
    fade: true,
    easing: 'swing',
    speed: 700,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true
  };
  // Init slick carousel
  $('.slick-slider').slick(slickOpts);
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
p,
figure,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
dl,
li,
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
}

/* Slider */

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slick-dots li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #b3a8ae;
}

.slick-dots li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-slider">
  <div class="slick-slider__i">
    <div class="slick-slider__img-wrapp">
      <img src="http://rdironworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/dummy-200x200.png" alt="" class="slick-slider__img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider__i">
    <div class="slick-slider__img-wrapp">
      <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/f/f8/Stand-out-in-the-crowd-300x300.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090904155448" alt="" class="slick-slider__img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider__i">
    <div class="slick-slider__img-wrapp">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/446356636710363136/OYIaJ1KK.png" alt="" class="slick-slider__img"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Для чего вам "техническим" блокам высоту в 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Родительский контейнер не содержит `CSS` свойста `height`, а это значит, что дочерние блоки не могут просчитать высоту в 100% от него и их высота зависит от контента.

---

Вам нужно задать для `slick-slider` фиксированую высоту и всем его дочерним элементам `height: 100% или inherit`.

Comment: но slick-slider имеют высоту, а родитель элемент имеет максимальную высоту, относительно самого большого блока.

Comment: Их высота по умолчанию `auto`, это значит, что определяется она исходя из контента. И все ваши блоки с `height: 100%` отображаются как со значением `auto`, так как высота не задана явно.

Comment: я вроде уловил суть. сейчас прочту про высоту, и если что, отмечу ваш вопрос.